# point cloud display issue

Tags: settings, viewport, display, meshlab

I had been importing point clouds into Meshlab without issues on my old PC, but new PC is acting weird. Looks like a display setting, but I can't find anything that changes the effect (see .jpg).
Cloud is relatively small, but contains big xyz numbers formated as quite long strings. Zooming around points are only seen in rows (like they are layered). Anyone have a clue why this might be happening?

[image]

PS: point cloud is .txt file of a tree, btw.

Comment: Just wanted to add that I uninstalled/reinstalled ML after the above post.  I also used cloudcompare to export this same data to a .ply. The results after import into Meshlab were even worse. I also wanted to mention that I can import .obj's and .stl's without any issues. This points my suspicions to a setting (or a glitch) in Meshlab related to displaying point cloud data. I can provide the data to anyone willing to look at it. I also dialed back the decimal precision of the xyz's, but had the same result.

Comment: Sheesh. Finally figured it out. Meshlab, like Cloudcompare, doesn't like big xyz number strings, so global shifts are needed to pull the data into "range". Found the answer through this thread: https://sourceforge.net/p/meshlab/discussion/499533/thread/e9d2913f2d/?limit=25 and this one: http://www.danielgm.net/cc/forum/viewtopic.php?t=616

Comment: Hi Robert, I think that your last comment is relevant and should be posted as an answer instead of as a comment, so it can help other people. Could you please answer your own question with the text of your comment?